# XML to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm trying to take these 4 different attributes from my XML and convert them into table data. I've set up a loop to feed the information in. However, I get a syntax error, unexpected T_STRING when I try to run this. What am I missing?

```
foreach ($xml->machine as $machine)
{
   "INSERT INTO 'table' (id, filePointer, amount, description) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s','%s')",
    mysql_real_escape_string('$machine->id'),
    mysql_real_escape_string('$machine->images->image->filePointer'),
    mysql_real_escape_string('$machine->advertised_price->amount'),
mysql_real_escape_string('$machine>description'))
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to assign that string to a variable? Maybe you mean to run it through `sprintf`, too?

Comment: Why are you writing brand new code using the deprecated and soon to be removed entirely, mysql_ api?  You should be using mysqli or pdo at this point, and in either case, with bind variables you would not need to escape the strings --- just pass the bound variables.

Comment: Also, every answer has glossed over the fact that 'table' actually needs to be \`table\` although there's no compelling reason to use the backtics in the table name unless it's a mysql keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what this might look like with mysqli....

```
$db = new mysqli(hostname, username, password, database);
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (id, filePointer, amount, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
) 
foreach ($xml->machine as $machine) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $machine->id, $machine->images->image->filePointer, $machine->advertised_price->amount, $machine->description);
    // Execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. This one is particularly useful. However, now I'm getting this error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: Something about how my table is set up?

Comment: @DNielsen: If an answer does not work for you, don't accept it. What you did was duplicating the question then. Also consider how you can improve your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple syntax issues, in addition to not actually calling mysql_query.

Try this:

```
foreach ($xml->machine as $machine)
{
   $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO 'table' (id, filePointer, amount, description) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s','%s')",
     mysql_real_escape_string($machine->id),
     mysql_real_escape_string($machine->images->image->filePointer),
     mysql_real_escape_string($machine->advertised_price->amount),
     mysql_real_escape_string($machine->description)
   );

   mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you aren't actually doing anything with that string. You are simple stating that string in your PHP code, without assigning it or sending it as a query. Because you want to do a new query for each iteration of the loop, try something like this.

```
$db = new mysqli(hostname, username, password, database);
foreach ($xml->machine as $machine)
{
    $db->query("INSERT INTO 'table' (id, filePointer, amount, description) VALUES ('%s', '%s','%s','%s')",
    $machine->id,
    $machine->images->image->filePointer,
    $machine->advertised_price->amount,
    $machine>description);
```

}

Comment: Bonus points for using mysqli_* instead :)

Comment: Minus points for combining mysqli_* , parameterization AND using mysql_real_escape_string... (Nah, I didn't really -1 you. But really, lose the mysql_real_escape_string's)

Comment: still a fail... mixing sprintf with params, sort of defeats the purpose of using mysqli's prepare/bind process, however his code required it and you dropped that out at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a call to the `mysql_query` function to put your `"INSERT INTO ...` stuff in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
foreach ($xml->machine as $machine)
{
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'table' (id, filePointer, amount, description) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s','%s')",
mysql_real_escape_string('$machine->id'),
mysql_real_escape_string('$machine->images->image->filePointer'),
mysql_real_escape_string('$machine->advertised_price->amount'),
mysql_real_escape_string('$machine->description'));

}
```