# bind_param on a non-object

Tags: mysql, xml, mysqli, php

I'm getting this error and have no clues why:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

```
$string = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml    = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

if ($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO table (id, filePointer, amount, description) 
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
{
    foreach ($xml->machine as $machine) 
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $machine->id, $machine->images->image->filePointer, $machine->advertised_price->amount, $machine->description);
        // Execute the query
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }

}
```

Here is how I'm calling the table up:

```
//Create table
$create_table =
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table  
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    filePointer TEXT NOT NULL,
    amount INT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)';

$create_tbl = $db->query($create_table);
if ($create_table)
{
    echo "Table has been created";
} 
else 
{
        echo "error!!";  
}
```

Previously I was making my table in MyPHPAdmin. When I run this and then check my database, it is not creating a table OR updating it. I have checked to make sure it is connecting to the database and as far as I can tell it is working.

My new INSERT INTO code:

```
$stmt =  $db->stmt_init();

if ($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO table (id, filePointer, amount, description) 
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
{
    $id          = 0;
    $filePointer = '';
    $amount      = 0;
    $description = '';
    $stmt->bind_param('isis', $id, $filePointer, $amount, $description);

    foreach ($xml->machine as $machine) 
    {
        $id          = $machine->id;
        $filePointer = $machine->images->image->filePointer;
        $amount      = $machine->advertised_price->amount;
        $description = $machine->description;
        if (!$stmt->execute())
        { 
            echo "error : ".$id."<br />\n";
            break;
        }     
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: You are getting that error as a result of $stmt not being an object...

Are you sure $db->prepare is successful?

Comment: No, how can I test for this?

Comment: I don't think this is it. Other ideas?

Comment: try to give your table another name (not name `table` )

Comment: Thanks again. Done! I have also amended my test for the table (faulty) and now am returning an error. How am I creating the table wrong?

Comment: Please look at my update 3

Comment: Could my update3 help you pointing you to `double quotes` and a missing `comma`

Comment: Please respect that Stackoverflow is not your Issue- or Bug-tracker. Instead turn your individual problems into separated programming questions. We also have a reference on PHP error messages: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456) - Thank you!

Comment: Also please do not duplicate your own questions: [XML to MySQL using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17094624/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it with a `$db->stmt_init()` ?

```
$stmt =  $db->stmt_init();

if ($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO table (id, filePointer, amount, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

....

$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $id, $filepointer, $amount, $description);

....
}
```

UPDATE :

or use 'i' corresponding variable has type integer and `d` for amount (Double) .

```
$stmt->bind_param('isds',  $machine->id, $machine->images->image->filePointer, $machine->advertised_price->amount, $machine->description);
```

UPDATE2 :

- you should only execute one time `bind_param` (not inside the loop) !
- you should use `$stmt->close();` only outside the loop !

---

```
if ($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO table (id, filePointer, amount, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
  $id = 0;
  $filePointer = '';
  $amount = 0.0;
  $description = '';
  $stmt->bind_param('isds', $id, $filePointer, $amount, $description);

  foreach ($xml->machine as $machine) {
    $id          = $machine->id;
    $filePointer = $machine->images->image->filePointer;
    $amount      = $machine->advertised_price->amount;
    $description = $machine->description;
    if (!$stmt->execute()) { 
        echo "error : ".$id."<br />\n";
        break;
       }     
    }

  $stmt->close();
```

UPDATE 3 :

- you forgot a comma after `description TEXT NOT NULL`

---

```
$create_table =
'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table  
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    filePointer TEXT NOT NULL,
    amount INT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)';
```

---

Try this:

```
$create_tbl = "CREATE TABLE faulty(
      id INT NOT NULL,
      filePointer TEXT NOT NULL,
      amount INT NOT NULL,
      description TEXT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(id)
      )";

if ($db->query($create_table) === TRUE) {
  echo 'Table "faulty" successfully created';
}
else {
 echo 'Error: '. $db->error;
}

$db->close();
```

Comment: Like this? I'm getting a syntax error, unexpected "{"

$stmt =  $db->stmt_init();

if ($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO table (id, filePointer, amount, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)") {
foreach ($xml->machine as $machine) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $id, $filepointer, $amount, $description);
    // Execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

}
$stmt->close();
}

Comment: updated my answer forget one `)`

Comment: Looks like it works!! I think? I got no errors, but it doesn't seem as though my database has updated at all..

Comment: is ID really a string ?

Comment: I've edited the code up there to be more accurate to where I'm at with it. I had made some changes earlier when I was messing with stuff that I'm reverting. I'm not sure whether it's a string or not - sorry I'm very new to php.

Comment: Has `id` a `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute ? So you should use `NULL` : `VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)` : and `$stmt->bind_param('sss', filepointer, $amount, $description);`

Comment: I've left all the attributes blank. None of them should have anything specified except they're of the type: Text. Gave that a try anyway but no dice. Other ideas? I would love to crack this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us how you create `table` ? Add it to your question.

Comment: look at my updated (2) answer .

Comment: Please do not give answers in a way to feed help vampires. Instead educate for better site use.

Answer (score 1):

$stmt returns false because the `prepare` is not successful.

your sql looks good except for the table name, so most likely your database connection is not up.

try this code after you made the conneciton:

```
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $db->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

and this one after prepare
$stmt returns false because the `prepare` is not successful.

your sql looks good except for the table name, so most likely your database connection is not up.

try this code after you made the conneciton:

```
if (!$stmt) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $db->error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- It doesn't return an error.

Comment: That is, as far as I can tell the connection is working, so it must be something else?

Comment: also not after prepare?

Comment: No message if I do the test there either.

Comment: Would this happen if something is set up wrong in my table? they are set for TEXT input and other than that, no params.