# bind_param() on a non object error

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following function:

```
public function detail($detail, $table, $column, $value) {
        if(is_array($detail)) {
            $data = array();

            foreach($detail as $key) {
                $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `$key` FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = ?");
                if(is_numeric($value)) {
                    $stmt->bind_param('i', $value);
                } else {
                    $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
                }
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($detail);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $data[] = $detail;
            }

            return $data;
        } else {
            $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `$detail` FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = ?");

            if(is_numeric($value)) {
               $stmt->bind_param('i', $value);
            } else {
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
            }
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($detail);
            $stmt->fetch();

            return $detail;
        }
    }
```

This functions works well untill I use an array. The way to use this function is something like this: `$db->detail('username', 'users', 'id', 1)` This would return the username from users where the id is 1 (this works fine). Like I said the problem starts when I use an array so for example:

```
$details = array('username', 'active', 'registered');
$details = $db->detail($details, 'users', 'id', 1);
print_r($details);
```

The error is pointing to  `$stmt->bind_param('i', $value);` in the `if(is_array())`. I already tried the answer of: [bind_param on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096937/bind-param-on-a-non-object) but that didn't help me; I still get the same error.
I hope someone knows how to fix the `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` error for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: most likely because `prepare()` failed, thats why when you binded, it didn't work

Comment: might be because you are overwriting variable $detail which fails the prepare in next iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to unset the `$stmt` variable in the loop:

```
public function detail($detail, $table, $column, $value) {
    if(is_array($detail)) {
        $data = array();

        foreach($detail as $key) {
            $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `$key` FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = ?");
            if(is_numeric($value)) {
                $stmt->bind_param('i', $value);
            } else {
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
            }
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($detail);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $data[] = $detail;
            $stmt = null;
        }

        return $data;
    } else {
        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `$detail` FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = ?");

        if(is_numeric($value)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $value);
        } else {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($detail);
        $stmt->fetch();

        return $detail;
    }
}
```

This should help.

Comment: That is strange because it is working normal on my server. Did you added the line `$stmt = null;` at the end of `foreach` body?

Comment: I noticed I made a typo somewhere in my array thats why I still fot the same error but now it works. ty!

Answer (score 1):

I think the efficient way to prepare query without using loop is too implode values in the array instead of looping and preparing the query statement.
For eg:- if the query is

```
SELECT `username`,`active`,`register` FROM users WHERE ID = 1 //username,active and register can be used in single prepare statement by imploding the array


if(is_array($detail)) {
    $data = array();

        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT ".implode(", ",$detail)." FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = ?");
        if(is_numeric($value)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $value);
        } else {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($detail);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $data[] = $detail;
        $stmt = null;

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: This will not work because of 2 reasons: 1. you have to remove ` ` ` from the query otherwise the query will not be correct; 2. in `bind_result` statement you have to pass each column separately.